# Can we send other report file as attachment along with SSRS subscription report?

Tags: reporting-services, email-attachments, ssrs-subscription

I have a monthly report which I send to users every month using SSRS subscriptions (delivered by email.) My requirement now is to attach one more report as attachment along with Monthly report.

So the user has to receive Monthly report and attachment of other report.

Is it possible to attach/send other report file along with an SSRS subscription delivered by email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to attach another file with an e-mail subscription from SSRS.

I think the best way would be to create a subscription to put the file in a folder and then create a stored procedure that creates an email and attaches the files.

Here's some more detail on the sp_send_email:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99326/sp-send-dbmail-stored-procedure-send-with-attachment

[SQL sp_send_dbmail send email with attachment, pdf file got corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502480/sql-sp-send-dbmail-send-email-with-attachment-pdf-file-got-corrupted)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks @Fist, the above solution solves my problem